# Symbolizing predicate logic

Tags: logic

How to symbolize this?

1. Only a pacifist is either a gentlemen or not a fighter.
2. No pacifists are gentlemen if they are fighters.
3. Some members are fighters if and only if they are fighters
4. not all members are fighters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are more logic-like rephrasings of the sentences, which should be easier to translate into first order logic.

1. This means that for anyone $x$ (we'll assume variables range over people), if $x$ is a gentleman or $x$ is not a fighter, then $x$ is a pacifist.
2. For all $x$, if $x$ is a fighter, then if $x$ is a pacifist then $x$ is not a gentleman. More simply: for all $x$, if $x$ is a fighter and $x$ is a pacifist, then $x$ is not a gentleman.
3. I take this to mean: There are $x$ such that $x$ is a member and ($x$ is a fighter if and only if $x$ is a fighter).
4. Not: for all $x$, if $x$ is a member then $x$ is a fighter.

Can you symbolize these, using predicates $Gentleman(x)$, $Fighter(x)$, $Pacifist(x)$, and $Member(x)$?

Comment: I believe so. Which are you unsure about? The only one I'm not 100% sure about is 3., which is a weird thing to say or think & which seems ambiguous.

Comment: Is this correct? 1.(∀x)[(Gx∨¬Fx)→Px] 2. (∀x)[(Fx∧Px)→Gx] 3. (∃x)(Fx↔ Fx) 4. ¬(∀x)(Mx→Fx) which could also be written as (∃x)(Mx ∧¬Fx) This what i really mean. i got a typo.

Comment: 1. and 4., yes. In 2. you forgot to negate Gx after the implication. In 3., what happened to $Mx \land$? That's missing.

Comment: and if this is useful to you, consider giving it a vote or something.

Comment: Tips appreciated :) Thank you.